# How to uninstall helm chart using Kubernetes Ondemand Job

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have an Kubernetes application (Let's call it as collector-tool) (Deployed using helm). This application including Statefulset, Multiple Configmaps, Multiple Secrets, Service account, Roles, Services and other Kubernetes objects. I want uninstall it using one ondemand Job using the existing service account (Created in collector-tool app).

When I run helm uninstall command from K8s Ondemand job then service account also delete the service account which is used in ondemand job. Due to this my ondemand is failed. I need that service account for post cleanup activities like PVC deletion and some other cleanup activities. So I need a mechanism to uninstall and cleanup kubernetes activies from ondemand job.

Answer (score 0):

If the service account is defined in the Chart templates of the collector-tool application, uninstalling that Chart will delete the same resources you created initially.

I recommend removing the service account YAML from the Charts templates and/or adding "finalizers" to have more control over resource deletion.

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/05/14/using-finalizers-to-control-deletion/